@ConfigurationProperties не срабатывает
Имеется конфиг application.yml:
crypto:
    -   type:
            name: encrypt
            keyStore:
                -   alias: testcase
                    password: secret
    -   type:
            name: decrypt
            keyStore:
                -   alias: testcase
                    password: secret

И класс :
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "crypto")
@Data
public class CryptPropsTest {
    private List<Type> type;

    @Data
    public static class Type {
        private String name;
        private List<KeysConfig> keyStore;
    }

    @Data
    public static class KeysConfig {
        private String alias;
        private String password;
    }
}

Ошибок никаких нет, но дебагер показывает что ничего не баиндится. В чем может быть дело?

Какую версию спринг бута используете?

Версия спринг бута 2.6.7

Мне не нравится количество пробелов в -   type:. Может в этом дело?

Неверно описан список в конфиге. У вас не crypto должен быть списком, а type. Т.е., должно быть так:
crypto:
  type:
    - name: encrypt
      keyStore:
        - alias: testcase
          password: secret
    - name: decrypt
      keyStore:
        - alias: testcase
          password: secret

